# Why I'm unable to pass list to word_counts in textblob?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, textblob

As shown in the [quickstart](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html).

I have a list of words to be searched programmatically, but `.word_counts['ekki']` (as shown in the quickstart), is giving me an error.

```
>>> import textblob
>>> str = textblob.TextBlob("hello im programmer")
>>> lis = ["hi","hello"]
>>> str.word_counts[i for i in lis]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    str.word_counts[i for i in lis]
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code snippets or helpful links appreciated.

Comment: Using `str` as a variable is a *Bad Idea*, since it shadows the built-in type `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this;

```
str.word_counts[i for i in lis]
```

With this;

```
for i in lis:
    print(str.word_counts[i])
```

Your original line doesn't make any sense since you're trying to use a list comprehension as an index to acces a list.

Comment: Yes, thank you, i figured it out ,its is just simple python , Internally they  have used 
        >>> type(str.word_counts)
<type 'collections.defaultdict'>